# Vim: Alt + arrow keys to move selection within a line

Tags: vim, selection, move, arrow-keys

I use these keys to move a **block** of text (or entire line) to the left or the right:

Move block left:

`nmap <C-A-Left> <<`
`vmap <C-A-Left> <gv`

Move block right:

`nmap <C-A-Right> >>`
`vmap <C-A-Right> >gv`

But these commands can only move blocks or the entire line to the left or to the right.

I often have small selections of two or three words within a line which I want to move to the left or to the right. 
Does anyone know how to move a selection of text within a line using the `Alt - Left` and `Alt - Right` keys?

**UPDATE:**

As the above commands, I want to move the selection over the actual text p.e.

| | = selection

`one |two three| four five six seven`
`one four |two three| five six seven`
`one four five |two three| six seven`     `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean moving around (vs. "indenting within the line"), this is described in [this Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Drag_words_with_Ctrl-left/right); use the following mappings:

```
:vnoremap <A-Right> lholhxp`[1v<Space>
:vnoremap <A-Left> hlohlxhP`[1v<Space>
```

Note that these are for `:set selection=exclusive`; if you use the default (`inclusive`), remove the trailing `<Space>` from the RHS.

Comment: great! seems to work fine. Yes I had to remove `<Space>` at the end of your code. Thank you very much!